# Alamofire 4 and Swift 3 Image upload with other parameters

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to upload a image with other parameters the issue occurs when my one of my parameters have a datatype of [String]. The array will be empty on the server side.:/
With other datatypes everything works well.

```
  self.manager.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: imgKey, fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")

                for (key, value) in params {
                    multipartFormData.append(serialize(value)!, withName: key)
                }

            },
            to: path,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")

                }
            }
        )

func serialize(_ value: Any) -> Data? {
        if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(value) {
            return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: [])
        }
        else {
            return String(describing: value).data(using: .utf8)
        }
    }
```

My Params are `[String: Any]`

What I'm exactly doing wrong? :(

The problem it's definitely on the client side. Everything works fine when I'm using Postman or other HTTP Services

Comment: Share me your postman screenshot, let me take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    var index = 1
    for image in imageArray {
        let imageData: Data = (UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) as Data?)!

        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "home-\(index)", fileName: "home-\(index)", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

        index += 1
    }
    }, with: requestName, encodingCompletion: { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print("Image(s) Uploaded successfully:\(response)")
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("encodingError:\(encodingError)")
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question guidelines say not to ask for clarification but I don't have enough rep to comment yet.

How are you accessing the array on the server? How did you send the array with other services?

More importantly, it looks like `params` is a `[String:String]`. How are you adding a `[String]` value to that? Are you serializing it?

Comment: My param are [String: Any] and yes I show it below and update my answer how I serialize it.

Comment: @BilalReffas It still isn't working with the updated serialize method? Just from reading the docs that looks fine from me. I'd use some breakpoints/logging to make sure the `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject` method is returning true for the array.

Comment: @BilalReffas Alright, just to be sure, how are you accessing the array on the server? Are you expecting a JSON string and parsing it? If so, I'd try using params of `[String:String]` and converting the array to a string like Luis just suggested

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to upload as many images and parameters I want, I hope it helps

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in
            var secondCounter = 0
            for data in imageDataArray {
                print(imageNamesArray[secondCounter])
                MultipartFormData.append(data, withName: imageNamesArray[secondCounter], fileName: imageNamesArray[secondCounter] + "myImage.png", mimeType: "application/octed-stream")
                secondCounter = secondCounter + 1
            }
            contentDict = parameters as! [String : String]
            for (key, value) in contentDict {
                MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
            }, to: url, method: .post, headers: nil, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (dataResponse) in
                        if dataResponse.result.error != nil {
                            completion(nil, nil, dataResponse.result.error as? NSError, false)
                        }
                        else {
                            print(dataResponse.result.value)
                            completion(nil, nil, nil, true)
                        }
                    })
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                    completion(nil, nil, nil, false)
                }
```

Ignore the prints Lol

Comment: Are your parameters containing arrays as well ?

Comment: Yep, in that app I upload 12 images and 4 arrays

Comment: How is that possible your parameters are of a datatype [String: String]

Comment: I convert the array into Json string, I do that before calling the function sorry, its like this `let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: nil, error: nil)
let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me right know. The solution is really simple as you using MultipartFormData to uploading files you need to take a look to [RFC 2388](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt). To upload a array you need this format which is really important.
For example if you want to upload a array of strings you need to include brackets to your key!!!

```
Value: "234234"  Key: keyname[]
```

You need to append the data in a loop again and again.

For example take a look of this swift code using Alamofire.

```
for (key, value) in params {
            if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(value) {
                let array = value as! [String]

                for string in array {
                    if let stringData = string.data(using: .utf8) {
                        multipartFormData.append(stringData, withName: key+"[]")
                    }
                }

            } else {
                multipartFormData.append(String(describing: value).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }
```

If the variable is a valid JSONObject I append the data to my array. Again don't forget to include the `[]` brackets to your keyword.