# Cannot send image in server?

Tags: ios, image, swift3, alamofire

I am not able to send image  file to server using library alamofire. I am having issue with sending image file dynamically.The filename is shown in the server but image is blank.How can this be solved?

**Image code**

```
 let parameters = [
                "name": name_txt.text! as String,
                "address": address_txt.text! as String,
                "district": website_txt!.text! as String,
                "country": establishment_txt.text! as String,

            ]

            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.logo_holder.image!, 1) {
                    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "logo", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
                }

                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
                }}, to: "http://www.myeducationhunt.com/api/v1/schools", method: .post, headers: ["Authorization": "auth_token"],
                    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload.response { [weak self] response in
                                guard self != nil else {
                                    return
                                }
                                debugPrint(response)
                            }
                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print("errorss:\(encodingError)")
                        }
            })
```

> i am able to receive image filename but image gone blank.How can this
>   be solved?

Comment: Please check solution of the below problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021802/alamofire-4-and-swift-3-image-upload-with-other-parameters

Comment: Sorry i have checked this one already it doesn't worked for me ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can try this**

```
let parameters = [

               "name": name_txt.text! as String,

               "address": address_txt.text! as String,

               "district": website_txt!.text! as String,

               "country": establishment_txt.text! as String



           ]





        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

               if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.logo_holder.image!, 0.5) {

                   multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "image.jpeg", mimeType: "file/jpeg")

                   print("imgdatas",imageData)

               }



               for (key, value) in parameters {

                   multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)

               }}, to: "http://www.myeducationhunt.com/api/v1/schools", method: .post, headers: ["Authorization": "auth_token"],

                   encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

                       switch encodingResult {

                       case .success(let upload, _, _):

                           upload.response { [weak self] response in

                               guard self != nil else {

                                   return

                               }

                               debugPrint(response)

                           }

                       case .failure(let encodingError):

                           print("errorss:\(encodingError)")

                       }

           })
```

Comment: Yeah!! It works and i tried many ways Thanks For Your Help @ghimire

Comment: Happy coding my friend